# Uncountable set of different sized infinities

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Using Cantor's Theorem is is easy to see that $s=$ {$ \mathbb{N}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}), \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})), \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))), ...$} is a countable set of "different sized infinities." However, I am interested in constructing an uncountable set of different sized infinities. More precisely, I want to find a set $S$ such that
$$\text{card}(\mathbb{N})<\text{card}(S)$$
and for all $s_1, s_2 \in S$ such that $s_1 \neq s_2$
$$\text{card}(s_1)<\text{card}(s_2) \text{ or } \text{card}(s_2)<\text{card}(s_1).$$
Is this possible to construct $S$ with ZFC?

Comment: Presumably, you mean distinct $s_1,s_2.$

Comment: You can take the class of the initial ordinals, which has arbitrarily large subsets.

Comment: In ZFC, we construct $\aleph_1, \aleph_2, \dots$.  We can do $\aleph_\alpha$, where $\alpha$ runs through the uncountable set of ordinals $\alpha$ with $1 \le \alpha < \aleph_1$.  That is, $\alpha$ runs through the countable ordinals (ther than $0$).

Comment: Can’t you just do P(s) and then filter out the finite sets?

Comment: Doesn’t the ordinal with the continuity of the reals almost have this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it. Just extend your idea.

Let x be a set.

We define by transfinite primitive recursion

$P^0$(x) = x

$P^{\alpha+1}$(x) = P($P^{\alpha}(x))$

where $\alpha \in Ord$

As ∀$\alpha$ $\in$ $\omega$$_1$ ∃!P(P = $P^{\alpha}(x)$)

Apply the Replacement Axiom

A = { $P^{\alpha}(x)$ | $\alpha$ $\in$ $\omega$$_1$} exists

To force A to have all the properties you want, just pick a starting x that is infinite.

Note: The Enumeration of Cardinals is a well known example {$w_{\alpha}$ | $\alpha \in Ord$ }, which ( as the comments have mentioned) you can just take some uncountable segment of.